# How do I change the language in Firefox Developer Edition?

Tags: firefox-developer-edition

I can't seem to change the language of the browser. There's a language section in the settings but the language won't change when I choose another language.

I've tried to restart the browser and also restart my computer but the language still hasn't changed.

Comment: Use this link to download english version: 
https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/developer/?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The language on Firefox is determined by the language you download the installer for. So, if you download it from the mozilla en-us url, you will get the english firefox. To download the right Firefox in your language go to https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/all/#product-desktop-release to pick the language and download the right Firefox.

If you have downloaded Firefox, you can go to about:config in your firefox url bar and set these to true:

`intl.multilingual.enabled`

`intl.multilingual.downloadEnabled`

**Warning: I'm not sure if this can make the UI crash, proceed at your own risk!**

Comment: Please don't answer off-topic questions. Stackoverflow is designed for solving programming problems, not end user application support (which is better addressed on Superuser).